# T-SQL - Querying an Un-Normalized Table

Tags: t-sql

I have a Table 'Purchases' that has fields similar to this simplified example:

```
CustomerID  Item1   Price1   Item2   Price2   Item3   Price3  ... Item40  Price40
   111      15      26.00   23      5.00     31      2.75         36      17.50
   906      3        4.63   17       .77     18      3.74         19      22.60
```

There may be values in all, some or none of the Item/Price fields.
If there is an Item, there will be a price.
Items are always entered in Item# order. If there are 3 Items they will be in the first three Item fields ...

I want to join the above table to another table - Customers -  that has CustomerID, Name, Address, Email ... so that I can get a list of all Customers who have purchased Items 15, 17, 18 & 36. At this point, I don't want to show which of the required items each Customer has purchased.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Option (**less dynamic but more performant**), but you will have to list the 40 item fields

```
Declare @YourTable table (CustomerID int,  Item1 int,   Price1 decimal(10,2),   Item2 int, Price2  decimal(10,2),   Item3 int, Price3  decimal(10,2), Item40 int, Price40  decimal(10,2))
Insert into @YourTable values 
(111,15,26.00,23,5.00,31,2.75,36,17.50),
(906, 3, 4.63,17, .77,18,3.74,19,22.60)

Select Distinct 
       A.CustomerID
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Values (Item1)
                    ,(Item2)
                    ,(Item3)
                    -- ... Items 4 - 39
                    ,(Item40)
             ) B (value)

 Where B.Value in (15,17,18,36)
```

Comment: Thanks again @John Cappelletti! I commend you for going above and beyond. I will try both your suggestions and respond.

Comment: In the heading for my question I used the term 'Un-Normalized Table'. Was that a fair/correct assessment of the table design?

Comment: @Talay In my head, I see it as an Unpivot

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks! I will try the other [dynamic] suggestion as well but, honestly, I find it intimidating and mind-bending!! :D

Comment: @Talay Happy it helped

Comment: I would normally post a new question, but I think this one is related to what you already showed me. Edit: Sorry ... please ignore - I will post a new question.

Comment: SO Sorry! I realized I could not succinctly ask the question in a comment field so, in my 'Edit:', I asked you to please ignore. I have posted a new question with the words 'Customers with multiple purchases' in the title. Again, please accept my apologies.